# How to get a specific date range file count using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, onedrive, azure-powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-remoting

I'm using PNP Module to get my OneDrive file and folder total items count. The below script is working fine but I'm just wondering if there is a way to get only a certain date range file and folder count.

For example, I just want an item total count between CreatedDate 03/03/2011 to CreatedDate 08/31/2022 instead of everything.

Any help or suggestion would be really appreciated.

```
$SiteURL = ""
$ListName = "Documents"
     
Connect-PnPOnline $SiteURL -Credentials $credential

#Get the list
$List = Get-PnPList -Identity $ListName | Select Title, ItemCount
$global:counter = 0
    
$FolderItems = Get-PnPListItem -List $ListName -PageSize 500  -Fields "FileLeafRef", "Created","Modified", "SMTotalFileStreamSize","FileRef","File_x0020_Type" -ScriptBlock { Param($items) $global:counter += $items.Count; Write-Progress -PercentComplete `
    ($global:Counter / ($List.ItemCount) * 100) -Activity "Getting Items from List:" -Status "Processing Items $global:Counter to $($List.ItemCount)"; }  | Where { $_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "folder" }

$FolderItems.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming Created is a datetime type object, for a range of 120 days around today, you can try that :

```
$rangestart = (Get-date).AddDays(-60)
$rangeEnd = (Get-date).AddDays(60)
$FolderItems.items() | where-object {($_.Created -gt $rangestart) -and ($_.Created -lt $rangeEnd)}
```

If `$folderItems` is a powershell Array just remove the `.items()` before the pipe.

Comment: How would you have file created in the future ? :
) Jokes aside, you can show the examples relevant to the question with `$rangeStart = Get-date "03/03/2011"` and `$rangeEnd = Get-date "08/31/2022"`. Also, I would recommend the OP to use filter at the request (maybe through a CAML query?) instead of filtering after receiving the items to improve performance. As I haven't anything to try feel free to try and suggest =)

Answer (score 0):

I have reproduced in my environment, and thanks to @StephenP and followed his [SO-thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55822013/get-list-of-files-with-a-specific-date-range) :

```
$upperBound = [datetime]::ParseExact('08/04/2022 01:00:00',                                    'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',
                                   [Cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

$lowerBound = [datetime]::ParseExact('30/07/2022 01:00:00', 'dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss',                              [Cultureinfo]::InvariantCulture)

(Get-ChildItem "X" -Recurse) | Where-Object {($_.LastWriteTime -gt  $upperbound) -and ($_.LastWriteTime -lt $lowerbound)}
```

X- X means path of the files

[image]

Now if you want count, you can follow like below:

[image]